# Chef cookbook how to pass key values to a resource

Tags: tomcat, chef-infra, multiple-instances, cookbook

I am writing a cookbook to install multiple instances of tomcat on same host.
I have created a hash for multiple instances and this hash will have key-value pairs for shutdown_port and startup_port.
For eg -

```
instances:
      instance1:
        shutdown_port: 8005
        startup_port: 8009
      instance2:
        shutdown_port: 8005
        startup_port: 8009
```

For each instance (eg instance1), I want to pass "shutdown_port" and "startup_port" to my resource. How can I do that ?

Sample recipe call-

```
app['instances'].each do |name, attribs|

    tomcat_multi_instances name do
       attribs.each { |k, v| send(k, v) if v }

          startup_port          startup_port
          shutdown_port         shutdown_port

      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this:

```
app['instances'].each do |name, attributes|
  tomcat_multi_instances name do
    startup_port          attributes['startup_port'] if attributes['startup_port']
    startup_port          attributes['shutdown_port'] if attributes['shutdown_port']
  end
end
```